# How to allow Http in android 9

Tags: android, http, android-9.0-pie, android-network-security-config

How to allow IP with Port in android network_security_config file in android 9.

I have tried android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" as well but no luck.

Domain is like this: 76.43.50.157:4001

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android 8: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted)

Comment: please consider port number.
Above answers are not working with the domain and port number.

Comment: What is the solution?  I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks @Vishalkumarsinghvi

Comment: @shubhgaikwad Welcome brother.